# How is the electron density connected to the atomic number?

Tags: condensed-matter, photons, electrons, atomic-physics, scattering

How is the [electron density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_density) connected to the [atomic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number)? Is it proportional, one-to-one or maybe less? The background is the following phrase

> For an absorber, it is the density of electrons that is crucial in the
> range where Compton effect dominates.

http://www.radioactivity.eu.com/site/pages/Compton_Effect.htm

I'm not sure if I understand it correctly..  is (always) the electron density important w.r.t to the probability of photon-matter interactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of radiation absorption in tissue via the Compton effect, the quantity that matters is the electron density in its purest form: just how many electrons there are in a given volume. This is equal to the product of the atomic number (how many electrons each atom has) with the number density (how many atoms per unit volume), where the number density can be found as the mass density divided by the atom's mass number.

Here the atomic number is an important factor, but it's not the only one, because different elements pack at different efficiencies: if adding one electron to each atom makes them much 'fluffier' and decreases the packing efficiency (which does happen sometimes), then the electron density will go down.

Moreover, in biological tissue you have a complicated mix of molecules, and those will pack differently depending on the conditions. Thus, while you could in principle calculate it if you knew how much of each element per unit volume is in the relevant tissue, in practice it's going to be much easier to just study the electron density directly.